# Column ambiguously defined error with Oracle Merge statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem with this query in Oracle SQL.

> Errore alla riga del comando:18 Colonna:42
>   Report errori:
>   Errore SQL: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
>   00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"
>   *Cause:    
>   *Action:

This is the query, but i don't see the column ambiguously defined:

```
MERGE INTO T_HPSM_CM_UBIS H USING
(SELECT A.itam_relevant_appl_code as ret,
 b.service_id,
 b.it_service,
 b.itam_user_id,
 b.itam_last_name,
 b.itam_first_name,
 b.itrm_user_id,
 b.itam_first_name,
 b.itam_last_name
FROM
 (SELECT f.itam_relevant_appl_code
  FROM T_HPSM_CM_UBIS f
  GROUP BY f.itam_relevant_appl_code
 ) A,
 t_cp_list_itam b
 WHERE A.itam_relevant_appl_code   = b.hvb_appl_code
) s ON (H.itam_relevant_appl_code = s.ret)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET   H.service_id = s.service_id, H.it_service = s.it_service;
```

Comment: i think the problem is with "s.ret", you also have a "ret" as an alias on the 2nd line of your MERGE statement

Comment: maybe try writing a JOIN statement between A and t_cp_list_itam b

Comment: Why columns `b.itam_last_name` and `b.itam_first_name` selected twice with the same name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've selected b.itam_first_name and b.itam_last_name twice in the select list. Did you mean to? Should the last two have itrm instead of itam?

```
SELECT A.itam_relevant_appl_code as ret,
 b.service_id,
 b.it_service,
 b.itam_user_id,
 b.itam_last_name, -- 1st occurrence
 b.itam_first_name,  -- 1st occurrence
 b.itrm_user_id,
 b.itam_first_name, -- 2nd occurrence
 b.itam_last_name -- 2nd occurrence
FROM ...
```

If this wasn't an error, you will have to give the 2nd occurrences of the column an alias to allow Oracle to differentiate between the two.

ETA: Looking at your query a bit more closely, you're only actually using 3 columns from the source query:

- a.itam_relevant_appl_code
- b.service_id
- b.it_service

So you could just get rid of the other columns, as they aren't relevant to the merge.

Comment: The same error will occur if multiple columns in the result set have the same name, even if they are from different tables.